# How can I pass values in ddply based on a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I want to be able to pass two sets of values GROUPED BY the column `Category`. Is there a way I can do this using `ddply` from package `plyr`?

I want to do something like this:

```
ddply(idata.frame(data), .(Category), wilcox.test, data[Type=="PRE",], data[Type=="POST",])
```

`wilcox.test` is the following function:

```
Description

Performs one- and two-sample Wilcoxon tests on vectors of data; the latter is also known as ‘Mann-Whitney’ test.

Usage

wilcox.test(x, ...)

Arguments

x   
numeric vector of data values. Non-finite (e.g. infinite or missing) values will be omitted.

y   
an optional numeric vector of data values: as with x non-finite values will be omitted.

.... rest of the arguments snipped ....
```

I have the following output from `dput`:

```
structure(list(Category = c("A", "C", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", 
"C", "A", "F", "B", 
"E", "C", "C", "A", 
"C", "A", "B", "H", 
"I", "A"), Type = c("POST", "POST", 
"POST", "POST", "PRE", "POST", "POST", "PRE", "POST", 
"POST", "POST", "POST", "POST", "PRE", "PRE", "POST", 
"POST", "POST", "POST", "POST"), Value = c(1560638113, 
1283621, 561329742, 2727503, 938032, 4233577690, 0, 4209749646, 
111467236, 174667894, 1071501854, 720499, 2195611, 1117814707, 
1181525, 1493315101, 253416809, 327012982, 538595522, 3023339026
)), .Names = c("Category", "Type", "Value"), row.names = c(21406L, 
123351L, 59875L, 45186L, 126720L, 94153L, 48067L, 159371L, 54303L, 
63318L, 104100L, 58162L, 41945L, 159794L, 57757L, 178622L, 83812L, 
130655L, 30860L, 24513L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I always do is use an anonymous function:

```
ddply(idata.frame(data), .(Category), 
    function(x) wilcox.test(x[Type == "PRE",], x[Type == "POST",])
```

I'm not sure the `wilcox.test` functions returns something nice to concatenate into a `data.frame` by default, so you'll have to tweak yourself a bit. Alternatively, use `dlply` to end up with a list of `wilcox.test` output.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. Paul's solution doesn't seem to work in my case, although I'm using the very same data. I think the syntax for subsetting is in cause, but I didn't manage to crack the error.
2. Your data is actually way too small for any comparison to be computable with a statistical test given the structure you desire to use (that is, `Category` x `Type`). After all, if you look at the number of categories in your data frame, all have less than 30 values, and half have only one value:

   ```
   > table(data$Category)
   A B C D E F H I 
   5 3 6 1 2 1 1 1
   ```

But the good news is that I found a solution for you.

First, I had to generate a wider table. And because I was (very) lazy, I simply did this:

```
for(i in 1:10){data <- rbind(data,data)}

data$Value <- jitter(data$Value,5e3) 

data$Type <- sample(c("POST","PRE"),size=nrow(data),replace=T,prob=c(0.80,0.20))
```

I duplicated the table 10 times, added noise to the numerical values and reassigned randomly "PRE" and "POST" with the same proportion it add in the initial data frame. Note that the values themselves aren't really important here, I just to use the same data structure that you gave us.

This way, we end up with a much bigger table, and - more importantly - denser table:

```
    > table(data$Category, data$Type)

      POST  PRE
    A 4135  985
    B 2470  602
    C 4881 1263
    D  814  210
    E 1634  414
    F  815  209
    H  846  178
    I  813  211
```

So that's done!

Now we can work out a solution. In the interest of clarity, I have written the function that performs the Wilcoxon test separately. The trick is that it has to return a vector that will be incorporated in the data frame you need for your output.

Let's call the function `wx`:

```
 wx <- function(d){
 w <- wilcox.test(
  # First vector (x)
    subset(d, Type == "PRE", select = Value )[,1], 
    subset(d, Type == "POST", select = Value )[,1]
      )
  # c(1,3) returns the Stat and the P-value (tweak that if you want something else)
  return(w[c(1,3)])
  }
```

Finally, you just have to apply the function to your data frame:

```
> ddply(data, .(Category), .fun = wx  )
    Category      V1        V2
           A 2047794 0.7862484
           B  725554 0.3585648
           C 3071435 0.8459535
           D   80693 0.2112926 
           E  347314 0.3984288
           F   83304 0.6252554
           H   71762 0.3247840
           I   88874 0.4177269
```

Of course nothing is significant, given the way I constructed the table, but you have the stat in V1 and the P-value in V2.